# What does a dash or hyphen mean in the "Configuring grub-pc" menu?

Tags: grub2

In the menu "Configuring grub-pc", I get in the list of "GRUB install devices"

```
/dev/sda (1000204 MB; ST31000340AS)
/dev/sdb (1000204 MB; ST31000340AS)
/dev/sdc (1000204 MB; ST31000340AS)
/dev/sdd (1000204 MB; ST31000340AS)
- /dev/sdd1 (1000203 MB; /)
/dev/mapper/isw_daigcjadaf_Raid2 (1000202 MB; isw_daigcjadaf_Raid2)
```

What does the dash/hyphen mean? Does it mean that /dev/sdd1 belongs to /dev/sdd? Is such a device what is referred to in the notes given above the list of devices?

> Note: it is possible to install GRUB to partition boot records as well, and some appropriate partitions are offered here. However, this forces GRUB to use the blocklist mechanism, which makes it less reliable, and therefore is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that line is indented is to show that `sdd1` is a *partition* within the physical device `sdd`. `sda` ... `sdd` are physical drives as seen by the operating system. `sdd1` is a partition of a physical drive, namely the physical drive `sdd`. The hyphen and offset are meant to highlight this fact in order to make it clear.